# MariaDB out of memory, Windows Server 2019, MariaDB 10.1, 16Gb RAM

Tags: mariadb, out-of-memory, windows-server

My system crash several times per day with error "out of memory", i have tried many changes to the configuration file with out success,

Mariadb 10.1.43 runs in Windows Server 2019 with 16Gb of RAM, with out any other program running

this is my config file:

```
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
performance_schema         = ON
max_connections            = 512

key_buffer_size            = 256M
read_buffer_size           = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size       = 4M

max_allowed_packet         = 4M
table_open_cache           = 256
sort_buffer_size           = 1M
myisam_sort_buffer_size    = 64M
thread_cache_size          = 8
query_cache_size           = 16M
thread_concurrency         = 8
default-storage-engine     = MyISAM
default_tmp_storage_engine = MyISAM
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The settings look find.  See if turning off the `performance_schema` helps.  (You should switch to InnoDB.)

Comment: It does not work, with or without performance_schema

Comment: Bring up "Task Manager"; sort by memory usage; keep an eye on it.  Report what are the top few entries just before the next crash.  Also, are you running any queries when it crashes?

Comment: Yes, many querys, about 150 users connected.

Top 5 in Task Manager:

Windows Command Processor 1019.3 MB
Antimalaware Service Executable 63.7 MB
Servece Host: Remote Desktop 58.3 MB
Desktop Windows Manager  28.2 Mb

Comment: But not "mysqld" in the top 5??  Were the 150 running the same query?  (`SHOW PROCESSLIST`)

Comment: I also upgrade the RAM memory to 32Gb, but with out any changes

Comment: sorry, mysql is in services 1,009,184K 
150 user running diferent querys, I thought one of them could be and I have optimized them almost all, faster, shorter, etc., without any progress

Comment: That's about 1GB, correct?  Strange.  Is any software a "32-bit" build?  Is it a 32-bit Windows version?

Comment: No, is mariadb 64bit 10.1.43, and there is no other software, the server is just for mariadb.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!

In the configuration file I added the following:

`tmp_table_size = 1M`

If it is not specified, it uses 16M as the maximum size of a temporary table, although in the queries these files are very small, it acts as if it used the 16M on each occasion, I cannot find another explanation for this behavior. Thank you all. –